# Django _set.all filter not working in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views, django-template-filters

I'm trying to filter a list of objects in my database but I can't get it to work on the template using `_set.all`. The strange thing is it's something I've done in two other places in my project but I cant see why it isnt working this time.

**view.py:**

```
class GolfMonthlyView(generic.ListView):
    template_name="monthly_view/golf-monthly-view.html"
    context_object_name='golf_monthly_view'
    queryset = GolfMonthlyView.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GolfMonthlyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['golftour'] = golf_models.Tour.objects.all()
        context['golftournament'] = golf_models.Tournament.objects.all()
```

**models:**

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Tournament(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey('Tour', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**template html:**

```
{% for info in golf_monthly_view %}
 {% for competition in golftour %}
    {% for golftournament in golftour.golftournament_set.all %}
      <ul>
        <li>{{golftournament.name}}</li>
      </ul>
   {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The good news out of all this is in trying to work out my problem its forced me to use the Django Shell for the first time properly. So I know the relationship is there and functional, it just isnt displaying in the template.

Edit: The working thing:

```
class RugbyMonthlyView(generic.ListView):
    template_name="monthly_view/rugby-monthly-view.html"
    context_object_name='rugby_monthly_view'
    queryset = RugbyMonthlyView.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(RugbyMonthlyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['competition'] = rugby_models.Competition.objects.all()
       context['match'] = rugby_models.Match.objects.all()
       return context
```

**model.py:**

```
class Competition(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Match(models.Model):
    competition = models.ForeignKey('Competition', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**html template:**

```
{% for match_info in rugby_monthly_view %}
 {% for competition in competition %}
  *code*
  {% for match in competition.match_set.all %}
   *code*
  {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have `golftour.golftournament_set.all` nested in a loop on the context list `golf_monthly_view` (not sure why you're doing this), which I think is empty because the ListView QuerySet is wrong:

```
queryset = GolfMonthlyView.objects.all()
#          ^^^^ ?? This is not a model
```

If you yank off the outer *for* loop for example, the inner loops should proceed if the QuerySets are not empty:

```
{% for competition in golftour %}
    {% for golftournament in golftour.tournament_set.all %}
      <ul>
        <li>{{golftournament.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Its a bit of a mess but GolfMonthlyView is another model elsewhere in the project thats needed. Its also the same on the two other models, hence the confusion.

Comment: @JordanLashmar Well, the one in the current scope is the list view, so you'll either have to be import the model under an alias or change one of the names.

Comment: I've imported the GolfMonthlyView model as GolfView, which I should have done in the first place so thanks for pointing that out. :) I can loop through 'golftournament' on its own just fine and that also works when place inside the 'golftour' loop. The problem comes when trying to loop through 'golftour.golftournament_set.all'. Not sure if that helps pin it down at all?

Comment: @JordanLashmar You appear to be confusing `tournament_set` with `golftournament` which is a separate context variable and appears to be unnecessary here. Updated my answer.

Comment: I think I must be. I'm certainly confusing something. I just added one of the working examples. I've been comparing and contrasting the two for the past few hours.